# Extract "Mon-YY" from a date as a Date

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I am using this code to extract month and a year from a date:

```
to_char(to_date(i.CREATION_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Mon-YY') "Month"
```

It works as required, however, when I extract the report to .csv, the value returned (e.g. Jan-2021) is formatted as text. When I then load the report to Tableau it creates many issues as Tableau does not recognise "Jan-2021" as a date, but a text.

I have tried many solutions, including EXTRACT, or by placing to_date before the to_char (which resulted in "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" error).

Please, how do I make this work? Thank you.

Comment: That's a Tableau issue, I'd say, Oracle doesn't have to do anything with it.

Comment: In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary format that has no format and **ALWAYS** has bytes representing the components Century, Year-of-Century, Month, Day, Hour, Minute and Second; you **CANNOT** have a `Mon-Year` value and call it a date. This does not sound like an Oracle problem but sounds like a Tableau problem and you need to manage the conversion at that end.

Comment: Agree with Littlefoot and MTO; you probably want to leave an actual date in your query and have the front-end format it as a string. You could `trunc(creation_date, 'MM')` to get the first day of the month if that simplifies things on the front end. (You should be storing the value as a real date; the `to_date()` you have suggests it's a string, but you might just be doing an unneeded and dangerous implicit conversion.)

Comment: Thank you Alex Poole, Littlefoot and MTO. I wasn't aware of this. It makes total sense. I will manage this in Tableau then. Thank you again.

Comment: Tableau is quite happy importing dates as dates and will let you format them in a very wide variety of ways. You do not need to extract parts of the date as text in the source as this limits Tableau's ability for format the date and may prevent it recognising the value as a date.

Comment: In addition, what is the data type of 'i.CREATION_DATE" ?  If it is of data type DATE, then it is totally inappropriate to apply TO_DATE to it.  TO_DATE, takes a varchar2 as input, so if you acutally use a DATE as input, you force oracle to do an implicit TO_CHAR.  And depending on your NLS_ settings, it could very well return an error, or no error but incorrect results.    For furhter explanation, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to convert this to text before bringing into Tableau. Leave it as a date. Make yourself with familiar with [Tableau date functions and date formats](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/dates-in-tableau-the-ultimate-guide/), and you can solve this very simply.

If it's a date in Tableau, and you want to display as MMM-YY, simply set the default format of that field as a custom format of mmm-yy